# How to `sudo cat` the contents of a symlink

Tags: shell, symlink, cat

I have created a symlink `foo` to the file `/bar/baz` using

```bash
$ ln -s /bar/baz foo
$ ls
foo
```

Here `/bar/baz` is a log file that only root has read permissions for.

Now I would like to print the contents of `/bar/baz` using my symlink. But this doesn't work with `sudo cat`:

```bash
$ sudo cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
```

I thought that perhaps I need to "unwrap" the symlink using `readlink`, but this doesn't work either:

```bash
$ sudo readlink foo | cat
/bar/baz
```

**How can I `cat` the contents of a file using a symlink?**

Comment: In `cat foo`, the symlink will be resolved, so that  should work as if you had entered `cat /bar/baz`. Most likely `/bar/baz`  doesn't exist.

Comment: Aha, then I think the issue is that `/bar/baz` is a system file, and I have been trying to use `sudo cat`. I left this detail out because I assumed it was irrelevant, but I will edit it in.

Comment: *system file* whatever you think that means is irrelevant here. `cat /bar/baz` and `sudo /bar/baz` likely return the same error. `namei -l foo` might give you some more hints. If there was a permission issue, you'd get a `Permission denied` error, not `No such file or directory`

Comment: `if [ -e "$(readlink foo)" ]; then cat foo; else echo "Target $(readlink foo) does not exist"; fi`

edit:  This is just to show that @StéphaneChazelas is right, the target of the symlink isn't there.

Comment: @JeffBreadner, note that `[ -e "$(readlink foo)" ]` is wrong if the target of the symlink is a relative path (or ends in newline characters). In any case, note that `[ -e foo ]` will test for file existence *after* symlink resolution, no need to try and do the resolution by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo cat foo` is correct. (assuming root access is needed to read the file, otherwise `cat foo` will work just fine.)

The issue you're running into is that `/bar/baz` doesn't exist.

```bash
$ ls 
$ ln -s ./baz foo
$ ls
foo
$ cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
$ echo "Hello!" > ./baz
$ ls
baz foo
$ cat foo
Hello!
```

Comment: did you mean /bar/baz not /bin/baz ?

Comment: @ThibaultLEPAUL Yep, fixed.